# Interactive Email Form Not Showing to Put in Cloud Page Landing Page?

Tags: cloudpage, landing-page, response, interactive-email

Having a few issues with Cloud Pages. I've setup an interactive email landing page and then went ahead and setup an interactive email form block and selected the corresponding cloud page email form landing page. The interactive email form has been setup with an appropriate data extension as well as mapping the inputs.

When I go into the cloud page I am unable to find the interactive email form under content to pull over and insert into any form block.

Another follow up question, when you guys create a content block to house the thank you message, which type of content block do you create in content builder, going through the options none of them seem appropriate, I simply need a content block to house an image and a thank you message or simply a thank you message but there is no option for a text content block only : A/B, Behavioral Triggers, Button, Code Snippet, Content Selection, Einstein Content Selection, Email Form, Enhanced Dynamic Content, and External Content.

Comment: I think you haven't selected the write cloud page. You don't have to insert the interactive email form in the cloud page. Your cloud page associates in the interactive form, by selecting the cloud page there. Make sure you are creating an Interactive Email Page and not the normal cloud page. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_create_an_interactive_email_page.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not creating the cloud page before setting up the form. Re-did this cumbersome step (MC is annoying sometimes) and it worked. You need to setup the cloud page first, then setup the custom form and point it to the cloud page. If not done in this process it leads to issues. Previous problem was that I already setup a cloud page and form then deleted the cloud page and form and setup the form before the page.